# Digitizing contour lines from a picture in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vectorization

I have a map with isobaths (water depth), like in this picture, and I would like to digitize them. Is there any tool or procedure in QGIS that can recognize the lines in the picture and create a vector file automatically?

[image]

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work properly

Comment: can you explain "but it doesn't work properly" it may be the data source needs to be modified to accommodate.

Comment: Raster to vector tool has not transformed lines in my picture in vector lines very well: it has created a shapefile with lines made by many small and squared polygons! My raster is a jpeg, not a geotiff.

Comment: @Mapperz If you follow the directions in your link provided it creates polygons, some polygons as small as a pixel, where as the OP would probably like polylines.

Comment: In addition to the isobath lines, your image has various point symbols, dashed lines, text labels, and watermarks. Unfortunately, it's not easy to extract vector lines from such a complicated image. It will help if you can manipulate the original image to make the isobaths more prominent (eg by adjusting the contrast, brightness and saturation) before running the `polygonize` tool. After polygonizing you will still have to do some manual cleanup.

Comment: Perhaps this https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Trace_vector_contours_from_a_scanned_map gives useful hints.

Comment: Thank you @user30184, this procedure seems good, I will try it!